# Change kubernetes --service-cluster-ip-range after the cluster is initialized

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

After initializing kubernetes multimaster cluster I realized that my --service-cluster-ip-range overlaps with actual hosts subnet. A lot of services IPs are overlaping with actual kube node hosts IPs. Now because of that I see a lot of issues in kubedns pods like below:

getsockopt: no route to host

My LAN is: 10.100.0.0/24
Kube service subnet is: 10.96.0.0/12

Now I want to change this in the kube-api pods yamls after removing all the services, but it won't allow me saying that specific section is not a subject o be changed. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: How are you trying to change it?